# Force KO to update automatically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I have two viewModels, one has a document style database in an observable:

```
var databaseViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.database = ko.observableArray([]).publishesTo("database");
}

var calcViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.replicatedDatabase = ko.observableArray([]).subscribeTo("database");
}
```

These get applied thusly:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    databaseViewModel: new databaseViewModel(),
    calcViewModel: new calcViewModel()
});
```

The only problem is, that the drop down box tied to `replicatedDatabase` doesn't show any items. I know I can force a binding update:

```
database.valueHasMutated();
```

But I don't know where and when.

I have tried after the `ko.applyBindings` however, I'm not sure how to access the newly created `databaseViewModel`. I've tried inside `databaseViewModel` after it has been created, but I believe that KO automatically updates the bindings when they've been binded, so not sure this actually makes a difference, it didnt on the dropdowns anyways.

I'm not really sure what I should be doing here.

For reference, I'm using `knockout-postbox` to do message bus style communications, `subscribeTo` and `publishesTo`. So as soon as the `database` observable is changed it will notify all subscribers, so I thought that maybe `replicatedDatabase` would have been update in the instance that `databaseViewModel` was initiated.

Comment: The trick to using KO smoothly is to *only* update/bind observables. These observables might themselves be an object-graph of separate observables; in such cases, where a container itself is updated, use something like `with/withBindings` to "unwrap" the container such that contained observables can be trivially bound.

Comment: Im not even sure how that applys to my question, my observable is updated with all the valuess, therefore should update the messagebus, but its doesnt...... so there is guna have to be another solution

Comment: `databaseViewModel` is not an observable; if it were it could be updated consistently, like any observable. This is why it is hard to "access the newly created databaseViewModel". (The real issue likely comes down to binding to stale observables - as KO binds *per observable* - as there is no cascading observable chain to follow/update.)

Comment: i said in my post @Navelpluisje ....

Comment: i know its not........ @user2864740

Comment: In the documentation of knockout-postbox they write about publishOn in stead of publishesTo.

They also make database an observable and not an array. That's how I think they bind to the database.

Comment: Sorry i do use publishOn, my mistake! What database, the property of the viewmodel is an obsevable but viewmodel itself isnt

Comment: Can you reproduce your scenario based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/43mVw/ ?

Comment: @RPNiemeyer hi, I watched your 2013 dev video and got a lot of great tips that I could employ in my simple web application to make it work, in your words, more knockout. I'll post my answer, I took the menu system from your postbox blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, rather than force knockout to update the values I chose a different approach.

Realistically speaking the page would initially be populated with some data from a server, so with this in mind I proceeded by making a global variable holding the initial data:

```
var serverData = [{}];
```

Then just simply populate the `observableArray`'s using Ryan Niemeyer mapping function:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.map = function ( data, Constructor) {
    var mapped = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
        return new Constructor(item);
    });

    this(mapped);

    return this;
};
```

This way both `viewModel`'s start off with the initial data, and when the database `viewModel` gets updated this permeates through to the other `viewModel`'s